# PyQt and QThreads: separate threads still freezing main GUI thread?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qthread

I am trying to do some work in a separate thread, in Python. I'm using PyQt so my threads are QThreads.

The work itself involves loading large images with PIL and converting the image to a QImage.

Here is an example of some code that loads an image over and over within a worker thread:

```
class testThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            im = Image.open('c:\zheadline.tif')
            try:
                imgData = ImageQt.ImageQt(im)
                print (imgData.width())
            except:
                print ("Image load error")
```

The image is quite large (16k), so it can take a couple of seconds to actually load it. However, during this time, the GUI becomes very unresponsive, often freezing for a few hundred milliseconds.

Why is this? My machine has 16 cores so there's no reason why the work from 1 thread would cause a slowdown in all of the others, right?

Basically I want to be able to load these large images in the background without interrupting the user experience at all. Does anyone have any ideas how I can push the main work off to another thread without disturbing the main GUI thread at all?

Some other info: I'm starting the QThreads with 'thread.start()'. Also, the GUI doesn't completely freeze during the load time...it just becomes extremely laggy and slow, freezing intermittently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python interpreter can only run in one thread at a time (read about the Global Interpreter Lock), so probably one or both of Image.open and ImageQt.ImageQt is doing a lot of work in python without releasing the GIL.

A possible solution is to load images in a separate process and transfer the data via shared memory. Pyqtgraph supports remote widget rendering this way: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/widgets/RemoteGraphicsView.py. See the 'remoteSceneChanged' method for how the QImage was reconstructed from shared memory.

Comment: Thank you! Your post pointed me in the right direction, although I've ended up using multiprocessing queues to get the data from the separate process, instead of mmap.

Comment: Link not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

Per ["Python, Threads & Qt: Boom!" - Teijo Holzer (Kiwi Pycon 2019)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol5IuJyw-Tg), [Multithreading with Qt / qthread - Giuseppe D’Angelo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcSsjxhazu0), and the Qt docs, you cannot call the following objects from outside the main thread:

1. `QWidget`
2. `QQuickItem`
3. `QPixmap`
4. Generally, all drawing/visible/widget events

Hence, I suspect passing `im` to `ImageQt.ImageQt(im)` in the secondary thread is causing the problem. I would recommend doing that in the main thread and just do the file opening (`Image.open`) in your `QThread`.